# Wordpress $args select query from multiple custom post with custom category check

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hi to all I want to create $args query to check that if custom post has category then check if category value is none or not if not then check if custom field value is true or false. and for other post type that category is not available.

here is my code

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $page_no,
    'post_type' => array('ct_photo', 'ct_event', 'ct_video', 'ct_thought'),
    //'post_type' => 'ct_video',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'vid_category',
            'compare' => 'IN',
            'value' => array(10, 11, 12),
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'vid_category',
                'compare' => 'IN',
                'value' => array(10, 11),
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'display_home',
                'compare' => '=',
                'value' => 'true',
            )
        ),
    )
);
```

Now what i Want
I want that this query will return result which check that if post type is video then it check that if category value is available then check custom field "display_home" is true or not and if category is not selected then it must be show in query.
and for other post type it will not check category.

i tried to use case & if but that is not working.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohkay I found my answer

```
SELECT wp.id, wp.post_type, wpm.meta_key, wpm.meta_value FROM `wp_posts` as wp Inner Join wp_postmeta as wpm ON wp.id = wpm.post_id where (wpm.meta_key = 'vid_category' AND wpm.meta_value ="true") OR (wpm.meta_key = 'display_home' and wpm.meta_value ="true") OR(wp.post_type IN ('ct_photo', 'ct_event', 'ct_thought')) and wp.post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY wp.id ORDER BY `id` ASC
```